# Weird behaviour runing pdflatex on terminal

Tags: pdftex, scripts

I'll try to summarize the problem. Consider the MWE below at `/home/user/main.tex` and also a pdf file at `/home/user/new.pdf`.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\sbox0{\includegraphics{new.pdf}}%
\edef\PagesNew{\number\pdflastximagepages}%
\PagesNew
\end{document}
```

Since both `tex` and `pdf` files are at the same folder, the code `\sbox0{\includegraphics{new.pdf}}` *should work*.

I have no problem running `pdflatex` from TeXstudio. But since I'm creating a script to be called within terminal from any path (for example, `/home/user/Downloads/`) the problem starts.

I think that `pdflatex` is searching for `new.pdf` in the current path when I run it.

**For example:**

```
cd /home/user/Downloads
pdflatex /home/user/main.tex
```

creates the `log` file in `/home/user/Downloads` and produces the error

```
LaTeX Warning: File `new.pdf' not found on input line 5.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `new.pdf' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.5 \sbox0{\includegraphics{new.pdf}}
                                     %
?
```

But it works if I run it in `/home/user/`.

**Why is `pdflatex` searching for `new.pdf` in wrong path? How to solve the problem?**

Comment: Relative file names are resolved according to the current working path of the pdfTeX run. The location of the TeX file does not matter.

Comment: In the `pdftex`  man page I read the option "`-output-directory <directory>` : Write  output files in <directory> instead of the current directory.  Look up input files in <directory> first, the along the normal search path."  I guess "the along..." should read " then along..."

Comment: @campa, I tried `-output-directory` option and it works to create the `log` file there. But does not solve the problem to search for the inputed pdf file.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, good to know. But any idea how to solve?

Comment: For example: `(cd /home/user && pdflatex main)`

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, great! It works. So 1st enter the directory and after run `pdflatex`. In this way I don't need to care about `-output-directory`. Thanks.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Do you want to answer so we can close this?